# Force programs in the taskbar to be in the same row

Tags: windows, taskbar

Is there a way to force two instances of a program to be in the same row?

This is fine:
[image: Two instances of a program in the same row]

However, if I open further programs, the previous instances get separated:
[image: Two instances of a program in two rows]

Ideally, the first instance would also move to the bottom row (similar to a non-breaking space).

The [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) doesn't seem to offer such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do the changes there, they have grouping, combining , re-ordering and I think the one your referring to is called "glomming". Your displaying that you do not want combining, but you want it to be grouped, but grouping of that type is called glomming.

This registry setting is supposed to effect that.

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]

Value Name: TaskbarGlomming
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: 1

`1` Should group the same programs, `0` instead allows the newly opened program to be in the order of opening the programs, I actually prefer not to glom, because I know easier which instance of the program it is. EX: I want the notepad I opened after I opened the CMDprompt, the order of the workflow, helps to recognise the item in the same workflow.

The taskbar tweaker of another type, used the word glomming in the settings? I do not see that word being used in this 7+ one you linked, but it does look like it has the features, just called grouping in there somewhere?

Comment: I've set TaskbarGlomming to 1 and even restarted my PC, but the behavior is still the same as before. In addition, I've also tried all the options in 7+ Taskbar Tweaker (à la trial & error).

Comment: Oooohhh duh,  now I get what your asking. The default is to keep these same programs grouped together, you would have to fully replace the taskbar itself for it to hop a group  down to a second line to stay grouped on same lines also. What your asking I have not seen created.  If this design existed how would 28 programs of the same decide where to go?  I think you have a feature here you will have to create yourself or beg the persons doing it to add that feature.

Comment: Because you can re-order things, with Drag-'n-Drop (left hold click an item in the taskbar move it around) potentially you could shift a few things around , and temporarily have a pair on the same row. I just tested that, but once there is more space for the titles than will fit on the row , something has to give.

Comment: Of course, there would be situations where not all rearrangements could be satisfied. Even if no such program seems to exist, thanks for your help!